# Html displaying line in wrong spot

Tags: html, css

I am trying to follow a tutorial so that when an input is selected the label rises and the line changes color. The problem is it creates a second line that displays in the middle of the input.

[image: While not selected]
[image: While selected]

It should display like the one on this site [here](https://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/gKGbxo?editors=1100)

I tried comparing the code then typed it exactly and it still isn't working.

My code is

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: grid;
  font-family: Avenir;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inp {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
}
.inp .label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #9098a9;
  font-weight: 500;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.inp .border {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #07f;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}
.inp input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 12px 0;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c8ccd4;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #223254;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}
.inp input:hover {
  background: rgba(34,50,84,0.03);
}
.inp input:not(:placeholder-shown) + span {
  color: #5a667f;
  transform: translateY(-26px) scale(0.75);
}
.inp input:focus {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}
.inp input:focus + span {
  color: #07f;
  transform: translateY(-26px) scale(0.75);
}
.inp input:focus + span + .border {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  . . .
 </head>

 <body bgcolor="#f4b942">
  <div>
   <label for="inp" class="inp">
      <input type="text" id="inp" placeholder="&nbsp;">
      <span class="label">Insert Values</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
   </label>
  </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not exactly same as the example link you mentioned. You have added `<label>` inside a `<div>`. `<div>` has a default `display: block` which is caused this issue. So there are two options 1) Remove `<div>` 2) Add change `display: block` to some other values like `display: flex`. It will work.

Below is code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  font-family: Avenir;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div {
  display: flex;
}

.inp {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
}

.inp .label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #9098a9;
  font-weight: 500;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.inp .border {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #07f;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}

.inp input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 12px 0;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c8ccd4;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #223254;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}

.inp input:hover {
  background: rgba(34, 50, 84, 0.03);
}

.inp input:not(:placeholder-shown)+span {
  color: #5a667f;
  transform: translateY(-26px) scale(0.75);
}

.inp input:focus {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

.inp input:focus+span {
  color: #07f;
  transform: translateY(-26px) scale(0.75);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  . . .
</head>

<body bgcolor="#f4b942">
  <div class="div">
    <label for="inp" class="inp">
      <input type="text" id="inp" placeholder="&nbsp;">
      <span class="label">Insert Values</span>
      <span class="border"></span>
   </label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix how it doesn't type on the line? The text seems to be a whole letter above the line.

Comment: Yeah I was just looking at it but couldn't figure out how to implement it, when I tried changing some to 'flex' it messed up the formatting. Also when I run your snippet it still doesn't type the words exactly on the line is there a way to fix that? Here is my updated code. https://gist.github.com/KingBlueSapphire/c4d6c76a4582a454041689706527c7f1

Comment: @Dan my answer is same as this (https://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/gKGbxo?editors=1100) codepen example you shared i.e. in this example as well text is **not exactly on line**. It is new requirement which you have not mentioned in your original question.